# Using a gem from a private bitbucket repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

I have a rails gem that I created and I stored on bitbucket.

I'm including this gem in my gemfile:

```
gem 'admin', '0.1.0', bitbucket: 'myaccount/admin'
```

I can't access this particular git repo because I made it private, but I still want to use it!

When I push my app to Digital Ocean, it can't bundle the gems because it can't find this gem. Is there any way for me to keep my git repo private while still being able to reference it in my gemfile?

Comment: you ever get this solved?

Comment: @RockwellRice Yes, I did. I'll get code in a bit

Answer (score 2):

Yes but you will need to use an app username and password to authorize.

```
gem 'your_gem_name', git: "https://bit_username:bit_password@bitbucket.com/bit_username/bit_repo_name.git
```

Obviously you would likely want to set the [app username and password](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html) as environment variables instead of hard coding them in and pushing the credentials to the repo.  But I wanted to make the syntax clear here.

Comment: I see that the URL you gave has github. The HTTPS URL for Bit bucket is a little different. I've tried looking up the documentation, but ive only found how to include gems that are public.

Comment: Right, so you should just be able to replace the url with bitbucket, and of course use those credentials.

Comment: It still can't find it. I'm using the `figaro gem` to handle environment variables. Do you think that might have something to do with it?

Comment: You will have to set production environments variables in heroku.

Comment: Oops, this is a little embarassing. I'm actually using digital ocean. I think it was out of force of habit that I mentioned Heroku

Comment: Ok so gemfile code is the same, set env variables however you do in digital ocean